# How do I find out which user I had this conversation with?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

In [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48849457#48849457) chatroom I'd expect there to be a short exchange between me and another user about the issue of comments being deleted because they express opinions that offend someone. However, those comments aren't there for some reason.

**Question:** How do I find out who I was talking to so that I can discuss this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only comment you made or that was @ addressed to you that wasn't copied to the chat room was one made to https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/13301/gillonba

They do not seem to be in the room and I cannot seem to super ping them into the room. It is probably better to create a new room to discuss comment deletion anyways.

Comment: Thanks. $\;\;\!\!$